# Impedance of an embedded microstrip with different sub- and superstrate

Tags: pcb, impedance, microstrip, dielectric

I have been trying to find a formula to calculate the impedance of an embedded microstrip where the substrate has a different dielectric constant to the superstrate (so the stack up is conducting plane - dielectric substrate - trace - dielectric superstrate) - with no luck so far.
Everyone only treats the case where substrate and superstrate are identical.

So my question is: is there such a formula and where can I find it?

Comment: Treat it like a regular surface microstrip (one sided) then rinse and repeat for the capacitance of the other side then add both capacitors together.

Comment: There are many bounds you can apply, but an accurate answer to a general geometry will probably need a solver. Please confirm, is the superstrate topped by a ground plane, so you've got asymmetric stripline, or is it open to air, so you've got dielectric-covered microstrip.

Comment: @Neil_UK It is open to air, so a dielectric-covered microstrip.

Comment: How thick is the upper substrate, compared to the lower one?

Comment: @ThePhoton Quite a bit thicker, around 1cm for the upper substrate vs 1mm for the lower one.

Comment: In that case you can probably ignore the boundary between the upper substrate and air, and use the usual formulas for the case of air as the upper material, with some appropriate scaling factors...but I'm afraid I don't know them off the top of my head. Adding a diagram showing the actual dimensions and dielectric constants would help make your question more concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your microstrip dimensions are substrate 1 mm thick, superstrate 10 mm thick, you could reasonably approximate your superstrate thickness to infinity. The upper fringeing fields are only going to be significant on the order of the substrate thickness.

This now leaves you with an approximate microstrip geometry, with different media above and below the line. If you scale both dielectrics so the upper is equivalent to air, then you can use existing approximate formulae for microstrip with air above and a specific substrate below. Increasing both er's back to their original values will increase the capacitance by that scaling factor, so reduce the impedance by the square root of the scale.

It's been a while since I used microstrip approximation formulae in anger, so they might  only be valid for er_sub >> 1, or er_sub > 1. You don't say what the ratio of your dielectrics is. If they don't meet the range of applicability for microstrip formulae, then that's not going to work. However I've just tried a couple of online microstrip calculators, and neither complains for er ratios even below 1. That still may not mean the formulae are valid for that range, just that the calculators have not implemented catches for this unexpected range of use.